# how to trigger MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

How to trigger MySQL query in every hour…

Is there any way to update record, by self-trigger SQL query without refreshing page technique?

Regards,

Comment: Are you sure you did not find that in the [MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)?

Comment: [`EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html)

Comment: Guys suggesting cron should take a look at what @ypercube linked.

Comment: Both solutions are interesting. Keep in mind that it's very frequent that you need a little more than just some query.

Comment: @N.B. would it be fair to consider both approaches as complementary?

Comment: ya it really comes down to if you need to do any php scripting. if so then you have to go with setting up a cron on your hosting site. if truely only a query has to run then use the mysql events handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html)

Comment: As ive been told - SO are supposed to give/collect solutions and not links. If all would provide links, and not code-help then we would just be a link-database.